# Please help me understand why one simple change breaks my compose/pipe function

Tags: javascript

This code works perfectly as intended:

```
function fn (result, func) {
  return (...args) => func(result(...args))
}

function pipe(...funcs) {
  let result = funcs[0]
  for (let i = 1; i<funcs.length; i++) {
    result = fn(result, funcs[i])
  }
  return result
}
```

For exapmle:

```
const reverser = pipe(
  a => a.split(""),
  b => b.reverse(),
  c => c.join("")
)

console.log(reverser("FizzBuzz")) //logs out:  zzuBzziF
```

But if I replace `fn(result, funcs[i])` with `(...args) => funcs[i](result(...args))` so it looks like this:

```
function pipe(...funcs) {
  let result = funcs[0]
  for (let i = 1; i<funcs.length; i++) {
    result = (...args) => funcs[i](result(...args))
  }
  return result
}
```

Then I get **InternalError: too much recursion**

```js
function pipe(...funcs) {
  let result = funcs[0]
  for (let i = 1; i<funcs.length; i++) {
    result = (...args) => funcs[i](result(...args))
  }
  return result
}
const reverser = pipe(
  a => a.split(""),
  b => b.reverse(),
  c => c.join("")
)

console.log(reverser("FizzBuzz")) //logs out:  zzuBzziF
```

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious, but I just can't get why this is happening and have been struggling with this problem for hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the previous function; otherwise, `result` just keeps calling itself. The value of `result` is only evaluated inside the function when it is called, at which point it will already have been assigned another value.

```js
function pipe(...funcs) {
  let result = funcs[0]
  for (let i = 1; i<funcs.length; i++) {
    let prev = result;//stored previous function
    result = (...args) => funcs[i](prev(...args))
  }
  return result
}
const reverser = pipe(
  a => a.split(""),
  b => b.reverse(),
  c => c.join("")
)

console.log(reverser("FizzBuzz"))
```

You could also take a closure over it using an immediately-invoked function expression.

```js
function pipe(...funcs) {
  let result = funcs[0]
  for (let i = 1; i<funcs.length; i++) {
    result = ((result)=>(...args) => funcs[i](result(...args)))(result);
  }
  return result
}
const reverser = pipe(
  a => a.split(""),
  b => b.reverse(),
  c => c.join("")
)

console.log(reverser("FizzBuzz"))
```

Comment: This is going to be one of those problems where I know the solution but will never understand how it works. It seemed to me that when new value is assigned to result, previous values is used one the right side of equal sign. So recursion would stop when it would get to the place where result === funcs[0]. Apparently this is not the case. Or it is but still don't understand something

Comment: @Alexl. The value of `result` is only evaluated inside the function when it is called, at which point it will already have been assigned another value.